# Corruption Versus Crimson - Hardmode question

Tags: terraria

I have been playing this game for awhile now. I have done worlds with Corruption, and worlds with Crimson. I understand the differences between the shadow orbs and crimson hearts. I have destroyed Crimson hearts in one world, fought the associated boss..and then farmed him.

Now, I am ready to enter hard mode. After doing some research I find out that Corruption and Crimson cannot exist in the same world. WIth that being said, you are required to destroy "The Eater of Worlds" in order to enter hard mode, and he only spawns via Corruption shadow orbs.

Since I am stuck in a world with only Crimson, I can destroy crimson hearts all day, but not shadow orbs.

Does this mean that I am never able to turn this world into hardmode? Are worlds only able to be turned into Hardmode when they have Corruption and Shadow orbs?

Thanks!

Comment: If your research led you to believe that killing Eater of Worlds would bring Hardmode, you need better sources of information. I suggest [the official wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enter Hardmode you need to kill the Wall of Flesh (Commonly refereed to as WoF) Not the Eater of Worlds.

The WoF is summon-able by dropping a Guide Voodoo Doll into lava (This will also kill your guide, but a new one will spawn in after a bit). The dolls are often carried by Voodoo Demon's, be careful this will be the hardest boss you've fought so far, by a long way. I'd suggest reading some strategies before attempting it.

For some more detail check out the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh)

Comment: You will also need to do this in Hell, because that is the only place where you can fight WoF